# connection pooling struts2+hibernate+mysql+tomcat+eclipse

Tags: mysql, hibernate, connection, struts2, pooling

I have an ongoing difficulty grasping the technical implementation details of connection pooling. I have read quite a few of related articles such as [this one](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/connection_pooling_with_connectorj.html)
and [this one](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#Database%20Connection%20Pool%20(DBCP)%20Configurations), but still not 100% clear. Is connection pooling tied to tomcat, mysql, or the other development frameworks (struts2, spring, hibernate)? I mean do each of these frameworks require special handling to work with cp, or do I implement once and I am good to go using whatever framework I want?

Is there a straightforward example that involves connection pooling with the all the above frameworks?

Thank you in advance.

Kind regards
Dim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trend in connection pooling for a long time has been that most frameworks who need/use this tend to to it straight out of the box, or at least it's usually included in the basic set-up guides. Every framework there is does not need to do connection pooling, for instance I do not believe struts2 does any, and spring-core does not. I'd certainly believe the spring dataaccess-stuff does, and it's probably documented in the basic setup guidelines if you do dataacess via spring.